# add-migration fails due to incompatability of packages

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a connection to a SQL Server database I created in Micrososft SQL Server Management Studio. I am connected using my current ip.

The day I opened the connection and the database I also created a table using migrations and Entity Framework, and the table was created successfully.

Returning to work after turning off the computer at night and then back at the morning, I try to perform add-migration in PM Console I get the error:

> Your startup project 'TowerOfPower' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.

Weird, but then when I try installing the package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -Version 2.1.0
```

I get the error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -Version 2.1.0
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

So I tried to fix this by installing other packages as suggested on the web, but still got the last error I mentioned for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a big contradiction about your framework types. Firstly, If you develope .NetCore project, you have to use EfCore for ORM progress. In .NetFramework project, you have to use Entity Framework.

*If we look at the latest error message,*
You are try to load incorrect nuget project. According to error message you are try to install  **EntityFrameworkCore** packege to  **".NETFramework,Version=v4.0'"** For this framework you have to use **Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0**

Lastly, If you use multiple project in single solution, you have to be sure about project frameworks types (exp: .Net or .NetCore)

[image]

When you use Package Manager Console, you have to chose correct project in **Default Project** ComboBox